# Liquibase clob insertion/update not working

Tags: java, liquibase

I am using Liquibase to update the existing clob data field but it's not working.

here i am mentioning the Liquibase changelog file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog       http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<property name="clob.type" value="clob" dbms="oracle"/>

<changeSet author="kuprasad" id="002_UPDATE_TERMS_WITH_INFOSEC_DOC_FOR_REQUEST_SPACE">
<update tableName="TEMPLATE">        
    <column name="ID"  type="${clob.type}" value="Some 2000 html char text like &lt;p&gt;A wiki space improves sharing,      
searching, and navigating pages, but also adds load on the server, cost, and may complicate            
collaboration.&lt;/p&gt;" />
<where>id ='space_request_terms_conditions'</where>
</update>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="tag_v2_3_3" author="kuprasad">
<tagDatabase tag="v2.3.3"/>
</changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

The above mentioned code is the first way. I also tried with delete insert but that way is also not working.

Mentioning the Code here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<changeSet id="001_UPDATE_TERMS_WITH_INFOSEC_DOC_FOR_REQUEST_SPACE" author="kuprasad">
    <delete tableName="TEMPLATE" >
        <where>id='space_request_terms_conditions'</where>
    </delete>
    <insert tableName="TEMPLATE" >
        <column name="id">space_request_terms_conditions</column>
        <column name="content" valueClob=" Some 2000 html char text like &lt;p&gt;A wiki space improves sharing, searching, and navigating pages, but also adds load on the server, cost, and may complicate collaboration.&lt;/p&gt;" type="CLOB" />
    </insert>

</changeSet>

<changeSet id="tag_v2_3_3" author="kuprasad">
<tagDatabase tag="v2.3.3"/>
</changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```

I am running the Liquibase command like this

liquibase --driver=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver --url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbname" --classpath="C:\oracle\product\11.2.0\client_1\jdbc\lib\ojdbc6.jar" --changeLogFile=db.changelog-2.3.3.xml --username=abc--password=bcd update

Exception:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "WIKIMETA"."TEMPLATE"."ID" (actual: 1994, maximum: 200)

Please check my approach and let me know the Issue here.

---

Hi,The problem has been resolved. putting the Liquibase xml content here that is working fine in case of Data update through Liquibase.

Fix:

Complete XML Content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org   
/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.0.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog 
/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

<property name="clob.type" value="clob" dbms="oracle"/>

<changeSet author="kuprasad" id="006_UPDATE">
<update tableName="TEMPLATE">        
    <column name="CONTENT"  type="${clob.type}"  
valueClobFile="clob/templates_space_request_terms_conditions.txt" />
<where>id ='space_request_terms_conditions'</where>
</update>

</changeSet>


<changeSet id="tag_v2_3_3" author="kuprasad">
<tagDatabase tag="v2.3.3"/>
</changeSet>

</databaseChangeLog>
```